# censurar uma palavra cadastrada em uma base de dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, trigger, procedure

Existe uma forma de censurar e substituir uma palavra cadastrada no MySQL através de uma procedure ou trigger por exemplo? A palavra no caso seria **Flash House** e preciso que seja substituida por **Old School**.

Comment: Tome cuidado com o caso do [clbuttic](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2667634/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-When-obscenity-filters-go-wrong.html).

Comment: E se você utilizar replace?

Comment: @VictorStafusa mas é bem diferente no meu caso. entendo a preocupação. a necessidade é de substituir um termo "brasileirado" pelo correto e mundialmente conhecido.

Comment: @RenatoSilva o replace seria antes de fazer o INSERT?

Comment: @FlávioKowalske sim, esta talvez seria a forma mais eficiente, já posto o código aqui com a explicação

Comment: @FlávioKowalske você está utilizando php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ideia:

Pegar as palavras que serão censuradas do banco de dados, e passar estes para um Array. Com os Arrays gerados, utilizar o `replace` para substituir.

#### Como faríamos:

Imagine que temos a seguinte tabela chamada `Censura`:

```
(Palavra_Censurada, Palavra_Substita)
('Flan House', 'Old Schol')
('Palavra3', 'Palavra4')
```

Em PHP passaríamos os valores desta tabela para um array como no exemplo

```
<?php
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, "select Palavra_Censurada, Palavra_Substituta from censura");
$ind = 0;
while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
$censura[$ind][palavra] = $dados['Palavra_Censurada'];//Passa Valores da Tabela para o Array
$censura[$ind][substituto] = $dados['Palavra_Substita'];
$ind++;
}
$texto = "Seu texto que será censurado"; // Seu Texto Aqui
$ind = 0;
while($ind < count($censura)) { //Conta Número de Arrays
str_replace($censura[$ind][palavra], $censura[$ind][substituto], $texto);// Substring
$ind++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo da sua aplicação é melhor fazer isso no lado do cliente com *JS*, ou no *server*, pois no servidor vai ser muito complexo e utilizar muito recurso da sua máquina porque essa `thread` vai ter que ficar rodando\escutando para quando encontrar essa palavra que já for persistida, fazer um `update`, sem falar na questão de segurança, pois como você vai garantir o `rollback`?

Comment: Imagino algo assim: quando um registro for gravado da base algo acontece e faz a conferencia e o replace caso necessário. será em apenas uma tabela.